# where does file data go in a device file?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, driver

I'm writing a character device file and would like to know if there's any way to have a section of data for each instance of a device file. I've been looking at the inode and file structures for a place to store a non-volatile pointer, but have had no luck. can you do this with character device files, or should I be considering something else? i need to have custom read and write operations with data for each file instance.

Comment: okay, i'm pretty sure that it goes into the inode struct. does anyone know, vaguely, how to go about implementing this?

Comment: Your question is unclear: *"I'm writing a character device file"* - are you creating a device file, or are you writing to it? *"any way to have a section of data for each instance of a device file"* - What is an "instance" of a device file? And what do you mean by "section of data"??? And why do you want to store data in a device file? Why not use a regular file (that's what they are for, after all).

Comment: i'm creating a device file. by instance, i mean a copy of the device file made by mknod. by section of data I just mean an arbitrary piece of data associated with the file, just like the content in any text file.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your problem? What device files are you creating? And what data do you need to store? And why don't you just store it in a regular file?

Comment: *"a place to store a non-volatile pointer"* -- If you've opened the device, and if the driver has allocated space for it in the device structure, then an app could get the driver to store this pointer using an `ioctl()` call.  But you lose this data when the device is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot store data in a device file. The whole point of a device file is that the data you write to it is passed to some driver.

You could theoretically store information in the file name, or in the group id field of the inode, but that would be *very* weird.

Your best solution is most likely to store your data separately. For example, why don't you create a regular file alongside the device file? Maybe use some naming convention to associate the two.

Comment: thanks for clearing that up for me. I suppose I could store the data in a separate file, it would just make the code much more of a headache.